# How do I hard/factory/whatever reset a 1.6 tablet that will not boot?

Tags: factory-reset

I have one of those cheap 7" China jobs which I use as an eBook reader and not much more.

Suddenly it won't start, by which I mean that I see the "BIOS screen" with the green Android robot and the OS version, kernel version and SDK version, then it shows a black screen with the word "Android" forever.

There is no software installed apart from the eBook reader, so I don't mind doing a "hard reset".

How can I bring the tablet back to life?

Comment: Contact eBay seller from whom you purchased the tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did any manuals or documentation come with this thing? Is there a manufacturer's website for tech support? Look for ways to get into "Recovery Mode" which should have options for doing a "factory reset".

Comment: +1 Sorry, no, it was a real cheap China-made, bought on eBay for $99 a years or so ago and has neither a handbook nor any indication of the manufacturer on either the device or the box.

Comment: Are there any hardware buttons besides the Power button?  Like Volume up/down?  Often the recovery mode is accessed with a combination of buttons held down while powering up. Try turning the reader off, and then while holding down Volume Up press Power to boot up.  If that does nothing, turn it off and try again while holding Volume Down this time.